# NHibernate: Getting "Invalid column name 'ID'." when i use Criteria.List

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate with Fluent, and I'm trying to do a GetAll type thing using `Critera.List`:

```
    public static List<T> GetAll(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        using (ISession session = Utils.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T));
                criteria.SetFirstResult(pageIndex * pageSize);
                if (pageSize > 0)
                {
                    criteria.SetMaxResults(pageSize);
                }
                return criteria.List<T>() as List<T>;
            }
        }
    }
```

My map looks like this:

```
public class GenreMap: ClassMap<Genre>
{
    public GenreMap()
    {
        Table("Genres");
        Id(x => x.ID);
            //.GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Name, "GenreName")
            .Length(1000);
    }
}
```

The underlying PK/ID is `GenreID` (not ID), but I've set the map up correctly (or so I believe).

So why am I getting that error?

Comment: `return criteria.List<T>() as List<T>;` lol....how about `return criteria.List<T>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the column name in for the ID in the map:

```
Id(x => x.ID, "GenreID");
```

Otherwise NHibernate will think the column name is the same as the property name, which it isn't in this case.

Comment: awesome, thanks, that was it. :) for some reason, i thought the Id() method automatically mapped the PK. :)

Comment: @bryan, how could Fluent possibly guess the PK name?

Comment: @Diego - Fluent guesses a lot... I wouldn't be surprised if it just worked, either.

Comment: @bryan Fluent does not guess ANYTHING, much less a column name that's different from the property name.

Comment: @Diego - you've never used automapping?

Comment: Yes, but you are he's not using automapping there.

Comment: @Diego One might imagine that NHibernate could ask the DB what the primary key column of a given table is.  So Fluent would not guess the name, it would ask the DB for that info.  But I'm glad that it consistently assumes the DB column name is the same as the property name by default.

Comment: @apollo NHibernate does not ask the DB for metadata at any point during SessionFactory construction.